# How to auto-accept Wi-Fi Direct connection requests in Android

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have 2 Android devices using WiFi Direct. On one device I can get information about the other device using the `WifiP2pManager` class, and request a connection to the other device. However when I request a connection, the other device pops up a little window and asks the user if they want to accept the connection request.

Is it possible to auto-accept these connection requests? I.E to be able to connect to the other device without user confirmation?

Comment: I can appreciate how this sounds a bit suspect. Like I am trying to connect to the device with out the user knowing. But we are looking at the possibility of using android devices as a base for vehicle tracking and logging. So these devices won't have a "user" as such...

Comment: It's not fishy. I work with him and I can assure you his purposes are boringly legitimate - we're trying to use Android devices for peer to peer proximity warnings within a corporate fleet - so a solution that requires preconfiguration is more than acceptable, not to mention less open to misuse.

Comment: @DavidKethel did you find any solution to pass that permission dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, do you really need to connect to the devices if you just want to track and log the vehicles around you ?

I don't know the scope of the project, but you could simply use the [WifiP2pDeviceList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDeviceList.html) that you get when you [request the peers in the WifiP2pManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#requestPeers%28android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener%29). You could get the list of the devices (~= vehicles) around you and could log this.

Connection is useful if you want to send more detailed information I guess.

Answer (score 5):

It can be easily done with the help of [Xposed framework](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial). You just need to replace the single method inside one of android java classes (see the link from snihalani's answer). But of course to use Xposed your device must be rooted. The main idea can be expressed in the following code (using Xposed)

```
@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam lpparam) {
    try {
        Class<?> wifiP2pService = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pService", false, lpparam.classLoader);
        for (Class<?> c : wifiP2pService.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            //XposedBridge.log("inner class " + c.getSimpleName());
            if ("P2pStateMachine".equals(c.getSimpleName())) {
                XposedBridge.log("Class " + c.getName() + " found");
                Method notifyInvitationReceived = c.getDeclaredMethod("notifyInvitationReceived");
                final Method sendMessage = c.getMethod("sendMessage", int.class);

                XposedBridge.hookMethod(notifyInvitationReceived, new XC_MethodReplacement() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object replaceHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                        final int PEER_CONNECTION_USER_ACCEPT = 0x00023000 + 2;
                        sendMessage.invoke(param.thisObject, PEER_CONNECTION_USER_ACCEPT);
                        return null;
                    }
                });

                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        XposedBridge.log(t);
    }
}
```

I tested it on SGS4 stock 4.2.2 ROM and it worked.
I guess the same could be done with the help of [Substrate](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/) for android.

Answer (score 3):

From my current understanding of the API, You cannot really accept connections automatically without user's intervention. You can initiate a connection, that doesn't require user intervention. If both of your devices are mobile devices, you will have to accept connection request on one end.

I have put this as a feature request in android project hosting. 
You can monitor their response here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30880

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the framework, you can ignore the accept window and direct send the "PEER_CONNECTION_USER_ACCEPT".

Base on Android 5.0, "frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pServiceImpl.java".

You must find the "notifyInvitationReceived", and modify to ...

```
private void notifyInvitationReceived() {
    /*Direct sends the accept message.*/
    sendMessage(PEER_CONNECTION_USER_ACCEPT);
/*
... old code
*/
}
```