# Automatically accept wifi direct connections through root

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifi

In Android SDK the Wireless P2P (WiFi Direct) API is provided.

I am developing an application that would require for the app to connect to other devices on the fly that have the same application and share information among them (text data). In order to do so I require that the devices could connect automatically between each other. I was wondering if there is a way to do it if you have root permissions on your device. And another thing is if it is possible to work around by creating some kind of automate response of clicking the OK button on the dialog of the user request.

Best regards.

Comment: Anyone? I really need help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the help of some classloader patching framework, like Xposed or Substrate. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18629705/1041475) for detailes.