# Class name for android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pService in Moto E

Tags: android, wifi-direct, motorola, xposed-framework

I'm developing a module in Xposed Framework which tries to access to Wifi p2p service to modify it. This is perfectly working on an Samsung Galaxy S3 by the code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18629705/2933485

It uses the class name *"android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pService"* to access the method. My problem comes when trying to run it on a Moto E device, the logs say:

```
E/Xposed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pService
```

So I guess there must have been a change in the name of the class. ¿Does anyone have a reference on what could be going on with wifi p2p service on MOTO E (2nd generetion)? The version is lollipop 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lollipop onwards **WifiP2pService** class was not be avaiable! So, alternatively you can use **WifiP2pManager** class instead of **WifiP2pService** class and you can't get **P2pStateMachine** object from **WifiP2pManager** class because, **P2pStateMachine** was not available in **WifiP2pManager** class!

I have found one class in github for accept p2p connection automatically using **WifiP2pManager** on this link

https://github.com/mdabbagh88/alljoyn_java/blob/master/helper/org/alljoyn/bus/p2p/WifiDirectAutoAccept.java

Try above class and i'm not sure it will work perfectly or not :(

Comment: in which versions this happens? The one that is working for me is jelly bean (now I understand why) but maybe I would like to try in higher versions than Lolipop. Is there also any specification where I can find this information?

Comment: Yes it was changed from lollipop on wards! so, you need check api condition if API < lollipop -> your old code else API >= lollipop -> your new code